# Show $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2}, f(x,y) = (x-y, x^2-y^2)$

Tags: calculus, functions

Show $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2}, f(x,y) = (x-y, x^2-y^2)$ is a bijection

This is my try
$f$ is injective if
$$ (a,b) \neq (x,y) \rightarrow f(a,b) \neq f(x,y)$$

If
$$f(x,y)=f(a,b) = a \qquad \forall a,b,x,y\in \mathbb{R}^{2}$$

Therefore is not injective

For the surjective

$f$ is surjective if
$$Im(f)= \mathbb{R}^2 \quad \forall a, b \in \mathbb{R}^{2} \in (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}: (a,b) = f(x,y)$$

Please someone guide me to the correct solution.

Comment: Your use of the arrow (e.g. $f(a,b) \to a$) is unusual, and I'm not sure I understand what you intend to say with it. Can you clarify, perhaps with words?

Comment: @SammyBlack How about now?

Comment: Oh, okay. I think you're trying to use the symbol to mean "implies", in which case `\Rightarrow` is the standard, as in: $f(a,b)=f(x,y) \Rightarrow (a,b)=(x,y)$. The single arrow is usually only used for functions, as in the title of your question.

Comment: @SammyBlack yes, this was my mistake. I confused the symbols, but I didnt finish the exercise.

Comment: I edited my answer to show how this might have worked if the domain and range sets were slightly smaller.

Comment: As the OP was edited, it makes the claim that $f$ "is not injective", which if true would by itself "finish the exercise" (by disproving bijectivity).  While @SammyBlack has given a good Answer, the Question is still lacking the clarity and context required by Math.SE standards.  I'm voting to close.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is false. The function is neither surjective nor injective.

**Not surjective.** Consider $(0, 1) \in \mathbb{R}^2$. There's no $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $f(x,y) = (0, 1)$. Why? In the first coordinate, we have $x-y = 0$. But then, the second coordinate is
$$
x^2-y^2 = (x-y)(x+y) = 0\,(x+y) = 0 \neq 1.
$$

**Not injective.** By evaluation, $f(0,0) = (0,0) = f(1,1)$, but $(0,0) \neq (1,1)$.

---

*Edited to show how to prove a closely related function is a bijection, inspired by (now deleted) answer by [Brian Chao](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/983045/brian-chao).*

This formula does define a bijective function $g: A \to B$,
where $A$ and $B$ are each a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ formed by removing a particular line:
\begin{align}
A &= \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid x \neq y \}, \\
B &= \{ (u,v) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid u \neq 0 \}
\end{align}
We are using the same formula, but the domain and range are different, so this is a different function.

This function $g$ has a (two-sided) inverse $h: B \to A$, defined by
$$
h(u, v) = \biggl( \frac12 \Bigl(\frac{v}{u} + u \Bigr),\, 
\frac12 \Bigl(\frac{v}{u} - u \Bigr) \biggr)
$$
It's a good exercise to verify that they are mutually inverse, i.e. $h\bigl(g(x,y)\bigr) = (x,y)$ as long as $x \neq y$ and $g\bigl(h(u,v)\bigr) = (u,v)$ as long as $u \neq 0$.

Why does the existence of an inverse show that $g$ is a bijection (and $h$ too)?

**Surjective.** In order to show that $g$ is surjective, we take an arbitrary $(u,v) \in B$, and define $(x,y) = h(u,v) \in A$. This is a preimage since $g(x,y) = g\bigl(h(u,v)\bigr) = (u,v)$, as desired.

**Injective.** In order to show that $g$ is injective, we assume that $g(x_1, y_1) = g(x_2, y_2) \in B$ for some $(x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2) \in A$. By applying the inverse $h$, we deduce equality of the preimages:
$$
(x_1, y_1) = h\bigl(g(x_1, y_1)\bigr) = h\bigl(g(x_2, y_2)\bigr) = (x_2, y_2).
$$